# change openmp to tbb

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp, tbb

```
#pragma omp parallel for private(x,y)
for (int j = 0; j < nDstSizeY; j++)
{

   for (int i = 0; i < nDstSizeX; i++){

        x = MapX.at<float>(j, i);
        y = MapY.at<float>(j, i);

        if (nSrcType == CV_8UC1)
        {
            Dst.at<uchar>(j, i) = Bilinear8UC1(Src, x, y);
        }
        else
        {
            Dst.at<Vec3b>(j, i) = Bilinear8UC3(Src, x, y);
        }
    }
}
```

I want make code to tbb but in local variable problem (private(x,y) on openmp)
my program doesn't work faster my tbb code is like this

```
tbb::parallel_for(0, nDstSizeY, [&](int j){
    for (int i = 0; i < nDstSizeX; i++)
    {
        x = MapX.at<float>(j, i);
        y = MapY.at<float>(j, i);

        if (nSrcType == CV_8UC1)
        {
            Dst.at<uchar>(j, i) = Bilinear8UC1(Src, x, y);
        }
        else
        {
            Dst.at<Vec3b>(j, i) = Bilinear8UC3(Src, x, y);
        }
    }
});
```

how can i fix it? sorry for my bad english

Comment: In addition to Anton's reply, I'd like to note that even in the original OpenMP version, it would be better style to declare x and y inside the parallel loop, unless they have expensive default constructors or destructors.  In general, any state is a potential hazard, because it might be accidentally shared, so it's good to tighten the scope of variables as tightly as practical, to minimize the potential hazard.

Answer (score 1):

This translation to TBB is inconsistent due to `x` and `y` are shared between threads because of `[&]`. If you want to keep `private(x,y)` as is while translating to TBB, add it to lambda capture explicitly:

```
[&,x,y](int j)
```

Or just declare local variables `x` & `y` inside lambda.
Otherwise, it causes a data race on shared `x` & `y`.

Another advice is to use [`blocked_range2d`](http://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/help/reference/algorithms/range_concept/blocked_range2d_cls.htm) which might enable some additional cache optimization:

```
tbb::parallel_for( tbb::blocked_range2d<int>(0, nDstSizeY, 0, nDstSizeX)
                 , [&](tbb::blocked_range2d<int> r) {
  for( int j = r.rows().begin(); j < r.rows().end(); j++ )
      for( int i = r.cols().begin(); i < r.cols().end(); i++ ) {
          int x = MapX.at<float>(j, i);
          int y = MapY.at<float>(j, i); // note: locally declared variables

          if (nSrcType == CV_8UC1)
              Dst.at<uchar>(j, i) = Bilinear8UC1(Src, x, y);
          else
              Dst.at<Vec3b>(j, i) = Bilinear8UC3(Src, x, y);
      }
});
```